# Replace every third comma with line break

Tags: python, replace

I have some data of the following format:

```
var =  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

If I use the following code:

```
var = var.replace(',', '\n')
print var
```

I get an output like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

What I want to get though is an output like this:

```
123
456
789
```

Which would involve only replacing every third comma with a line break. Is there a way to do this? I'ver had a look at some of the other questions on here and they don't seem to be addressing exactly what I am trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: @vittore the code I have provided in the question. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

spl = var.split(",") # split into list of individual items

print "\n".join(["".join(spl[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(spl),3)]) # join into chunks of 3 and add a newline to separate the output
123
456
789
```

To keep the commas:

```
"\n".join([",".join(spl[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(spl),3)])
```

Comment: actually ive just noticed something. what would need adding so that the output on each line retained the commas that weren't replaced with newline characters? so the output would be 1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9 if you see what i mean. thanks

Comment: @user3045351, I added how to keep the commas

Comment: sorry, ive got a cold...my brain isnt working properly today - didnt see it!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `replace`, try `var.split(',')` and get a list.

From there, break it up into chunks of three, and then put a newline between those chunks.

I'll leave the actual coding up to you.

Comment: that would be too long winded for my real data as there would dozens of elements to it. there must be a simple way or replacing every nth instance of a character in python surely?

Comment: There are ways to make this not long winded at all. Think of `for` loops and list comprehension.